# Please help me understand the ode45 usage

Tags: matlab

I'm studying numerical analysis and the answer for [this problem](http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DN1212/numpp08/utdelat/LabMPT.pdf#page=9) (the question is in English) that is solved with the following code:

```
p1 = -20.2090;
p2 = 17.3368;
p3 = 272.9057;
beta = 7.8*pi/180;
x0 = 2000;

c = @(z)4800+p1+p2*z(1)/1000+p3*exp(-.75*z(1)/1000);
cp = @(z)(p2/1000-.75/1000*p3*exp(-.75*z(1)/1000));
q0 = (c(x0)/cos(beta))^2;

ode = @(t,z)[z(2); -q0*cp(z)/c(z).^3];
IC = [x0; tan(beta)];
[x,z] = ode45(ode,[0 25*6076], IC); 
plot(x,z(:,1))
```

But I don't understand the strategy of the above code. I could think that a second-degree differential equation should be solved using a transformation from second degree to a system of first-degree equation but it doesn't look like that is done. I do understand how we get the coefficients p1, p2, p3, beta and x0, that the `c=`... is the speed of sound related to depth and `cp=...` is the derivative. I would like to know what happens next and why the code solves the equation when it doesn't do a transformation. What is the purpose and meaning of `z(2)`in the ode and why does the ode look like is does? I know that `;` in matlab means a second row and that `z(2)` means the second element in z, but why are those uder and how does it contribute to the correct answer?

Please help me understand.

Comment: Frankly speaking, your doubts about transforming second order ODE to first order system weren't true. Just take a look at this line: ode = @(t,z)[z(2); -q0*cp(z)/c(z).^3] . It's *exactly* a transformation from ODE to system :)

Comment: The vector $z$ in your code has two components, which represent the value of the solution (call it $y$ for clarity) and the derivative of the solution, $y'$. Your ODE function says to use $y'$ (the second component) as the derivative of $y$, and to use the equation you were given for $y''$ to furnish the derivative of $y'$. You will always proceed this way when time-stepping an ODE of order higher than $1$, at least when using a "black box" function like ode45.

Comment: The link for "This problem" goes to a PDF. Do you want to tell us how to find that question, or were you expecting people to dig through that paper to find the question?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews For me it opened at particular page with similar equations and functions.

Comment: The PDF has more than two pages. @Ian I count about eight.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're right, I didn't catch that. But the link is supposed to redirect you to page 9, which is the only page which is mostly in English (except for its title).

Comment: Not every browser, apparently, supports such internal links to PDFs. @Ian

Comment: Is it correct to say that the expression `ode` is the system matrix? Thank you for the comments and explanations. I think that I understand what the code does. It seems that ode45 is time-stepping with out system matrix and initial condition as arguments to ode45. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Programmer400 It's not exactly a matrix; the function "ode" passed to ode45 is the function $f$ such that $y'=f(t,y)$ (where $y$ in this context is a vector). Your equation appears to be nonlinear, so $f$ is not given by a matrix.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. You may take one of your comments and make it an answer. I feel that I understand much more now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying my previous comment:

The vector $z$ in your code has two components, which represent the value of the solution (call it $y$ for clarity) and the derivative of the solution, $y'$. Your ODE function says to use $y'$ (the second component) as the derivative of $y$, and to use the equation you were given for $y''$ to furnish the derivative of $y'$. You will always proceed this way when time-stepping an ODE of order higher than 1, at least when using a "black box" function like ode45.